# offline installing google app engine plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I downloaded the archive of [google app engine for eclipse 3.7](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip) but when in eclipse i start to install,it starts using internet to download the plugins. When i disconnect and try to install,it gives me a message saying failed to contact the site. Why is that ? How do install google app engine plugin offline ?

keeps on calculating the dependencies and then starts fetching content.jar which is already there in the archive :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find the required software". Hope this works

Answer (score 2):

Follow the link they are given instructions to install GP in Local.

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip

Answer (score -1):

To install the plugin, you have to drag and drop the plugin link or archive into eclipse if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: did i ask that ? How can i install the plugin offline. Till now in this attempt,eclipse starts using the internet to install even when they are present locally. And i do give the archive name in the install bar

Comment: try dragging and dropping the archive into eclipse then